# UNABLE TO COMMIT CHANGES FROM ECLIPSE TO GITHUB

Tags: eclipse, git-commit

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ecgH.png)
I have absolutely no clue what this means. The first time I committed my changed this message showed up but I payed no mind since I didn't know what it means. (still don't).

The changes that have NOT been committed are not showing up in the "unstaged changes" section after the first time. IM VERY NEW TO PROGRAMINNING ESPECIALLY WITH ECLIPSE. PLEASE HELP!

Comment: Looks like the remote `main` is ahead of yours. Don't you have a development branch?

Comment: This isn't a coding problem, it's a not understanding git problem. https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/using-git/dealing-with-non-fast-forward-errors

Comment: Just a _guess_ ... From the "non-fast-forward" message. I see a "fast-forward" message when I do a `git pull`. Check your local repo against the remote (i.e. github) as the message seems to indicate that your repo is out-of-date with respect to github. You may need to (re)sync them first. Careful! Although there's probably a git-like way to do this, I'd tar up my changes _first_, just in case. Then, git pull and/or git rebase

Comment: There are newer commits in your remote GitHub repository than in you have locally in active branch. Maybe you created or edit a `README.md` or other file via the GitHub web site. In Eclipse, you can fetch these commits via right-clicking the project and choosing _Team > Fetch_ in order to see them in the _History_ view. If you want to override them with your local commits, then go to the _Git Staging_ view, hit the _Push HEAD..._ button and check the _Force overwrite branch in remote if it exists and has diverged_ checkbox. If you want to keep the remote commits, merge or rebase them first.